Calculate average score
I have a table like this:



ID
score1
score2
score3
score4
score5
score6
score7




1
6
6
7
7.5
6.5
7
5


2
9
8
7
8
7
8.5
7.5


3
7
7
7
7
7
7
7



I want to calculate the average score of each row by removing one of the highest and one of the lowest scores and calculating the average of the remaining scores.
For example,
ID 1: avg=(6+6+7+6.5+7)/5=6.5
ID 2: avg=(8+7+8+8.5+7.5)/5=7.8
ID 3: avg=(7+7+7+7+7)/5=7
The following is the method I use. It is very bloated and the execution time is too long. Especially if there are more score columns(score8, score9...), more UNION ALL will be piled up.
SELECT
  id,
  (SUM(scores) - MAX(scores) - MIN(scores)) / 5 AS adjusted_average
FROM
  (SELECT id, score1 AS scores FROM scores
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id, score2 AS scores FROM scores
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id, score3 AS scores FROM scores
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id, score4 AS scores FROM scores
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id, score5 AS scores FROM scores
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id, score6 AS scores FROM scores
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id, score7 AS scores FROM scores) subquery
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id

So I would like to ask if there is a neat way to achieve my needs? (You can use PostgreSQL for demo, thank you!)

You can use GREATEST() and LEAST(), it's simple and executes faster:
demo at db<>fiddle
SELECT id, 
       ( score1 +score2 +score3 +score4 +score5 +score6 +score7 
        -GREATEST(score1,score2,score3,score4,score5,score6,score7) 
        -LEAST(score1,score2,score3,score4,score5,score6,score7)
       )/ 5 AS average_score
FROM scores
ORDER BY id;




id
average_score




1
6.5000000000000000


2
7.8000000000000000


3
7.0000000000000000



An example plan in a test on 50k random rows:



QUERY PLAN




Sort  (cost=3396.18..3455.78 rows=23839 width=36) (actual time=251.658..267.348 rows=50000 loops=1)


Output: id, ((((((((((score1 + score2) + score3) + score4) + score5) + score6) + score7) - GREATEST(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6, score7)) - LEAST(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6, score7)) / '5'::numeric))


Sort Key: scores.id


Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1328kB


->  Seq Scan on public.scores  (cost=0.00..1662.96 rows=23839 width=36) (actual time=0.020..237.222 rows=50000 loops=1)


Output: id, (((((((((score1 + score2) + score3) + score4) + score5) + score6) + score7) - GREATEST(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6, score7)) - LEAST(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6, score7)) / '5'::numeric)


Planning Time: 0.077 ms


Execution Time: 269.442 ms




faster execution can als be achieved by changing REAL to NUMERIC, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/WsH4UCiT

@Luuk Faster execution can be achieved, but swapping real for numeric will not contribute to the improvement - the opposite. Real (float4) is smaller and faster to process than double precision(float8), which in turn is smaller and faster to process than numeric is. Here's apples-to-apples with only the data type being different: 437ms and 27ms using real, which jumps to 988ms and 118ms using numeric.

Here's the doc on that: "The type numeric can store numbers with a very large number of digits. It is especially recommended for storing monetary amounts and other quantities where exactness is required. Calculations with numeric values yield exact results where possible, e.g., addition, subtraction, multiplication. However, calculations on numeric values are very slow compared to the integer types, or to the floating-point types described in the next section."

select s.id, (select (sum(x)- max(x)-min(x))/5 FROM (select 
unnest(array[score1,score2,score3,score4,score5,score6,score7])as x ))
from scores s;


First you should normalize data, so any addition of new scores does not have (much) impact on your query:
CREATE TABLE myNEWtable AS
SELECT ID, 1 as scoreId, score1 as score FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, 2 as scoreId, score2 as score FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, 3 as scoreId, score3 as score FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, 4 as scoreId, score4 as score FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, 5 as scoreId, score5 as score FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, 6 as scoreId, score6 as score FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, 7 as scoreId, score7 as score FROM mytable
;

Then you can do, and the query needs no change when you add a new score!:
SELECT 
  ID,
  round((sum(score)-max(score)-min(score)) / (count(*)-2),3) as adjusted_average
FROM myNEWtable
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID

output:



id
adjusted_average




1
6.500


2
7.800


3
7.000



see: DBFIDDLE
Your original score list can be retrieved using this SQL, which is easily adapted when a new score is added.
SELECT
  ID,
  SUM(case when scoreid=1 then score else 0 end) AS score1,
  SUM(case when scoreid=2 then score else 0 end) AS score2,
  SUM(case when scoreid=3 then score else 0 end) AS score3,
  SUM(case when scoreid=4 then score else 0 end) AS score4,
  SUM(case when scoreid=5 then score else 0 end) AS score5,
  SUM(case when scoreid=6 then score else 0 end) AS score6,
  SUM(case when scoreid=7 then score else 0 end) AS score7
FROM myNEWtable
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID

output:



id
score1
score2
score3
score4
score5
score6
score7




1
6
6
7
7.5
6.5
7
5


2
9
8
7
8
7
8.5
7.5


3
7
7
7
7
7
7
7




This is more correct and convenient to work with but OP's looking for performance, which it doesn't deliver. If you swap out conditional aggregate for a filter clause, it'll help a bit, but it's still a bit behind.

@Zegarek: Please do not fucus on the conversion of the table, but on the query results. I think they are faster. After that comes the improvement to change NUMERIC to REAL.

PostgreSQL:
select 
    id,
    (SUM(score) - MAX(score) - MIN(score)) / (COUNT(score) - 2) AS avg_score
from (select 
        id, 
        UNNEST(array[score1, score2, score3, score4, score5, score6, score7]) AS score
     from score_table) AS scores_per_row
group by id
order by id;


array function bundles all the scores into an array. Then, UNNEST flattens the array into rows, making it easier to calculate the sum, maximum, and minimum values.

Output:

